# failed to use xpath

Tags: html, xml, xpath

To crawl "https://www.reddit.com/r/CryptoCurrency/"

I used xpath to find li element has class named `"first"`

```
response.xpath('//li[@class="first"]')
```

but it returns `None`

I can't understand what's wrong

as I know `'//'` finds all elements in document. so I thought it will find all `'li'` elements

and predicate `[@class="top-matter"]` means if element has `class` attribute named `"top-matter"`, should select it.

Comment: Works fine for me with `python-requests` + `lxml.html`. Can you share some more code along with current output/exception? Also clarify why did you add `xml` tag

Comment: i use scrapy so i typed
 scrapy shell "https://www.reddit.com/r/CryptoCurrency"
 response.xpath('//li[@class='first']')

just this and doesn't work

umm omg I don't know why but now its working.. thx a lot 
maybe i crawled another page

Comment: Then it probably Scrapy issue or you simply did something wrong :) Share your code anyway

Comment: i edited comment.. thx for your helping! i did try again after saw your answer

Comment: It worked for me https://hastebin.com/pitudogaye.py